# Dbgrid calculation

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have a DBGrid and I´m trying to do a billing sheet but sometimes it doesn't do the calculations. How can I avoid that??

```
procedure TOrcamentos.DBGridEh1ColExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  percent: double;
  Unid: double;
  tot: currency;
  vaz: string;
begin
  if Dorcamen_SUB.DataSet.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
    try  
      Dorcamen_SUB.DataSet.Post;
    finally
      vaz := DBGridEh1.Columns[3].Field.text;
      if (vaz<> '') then
        try
          Torcamen_SUB.Edit;
          Unid := (Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('QT').AsFloat);
          tot := (Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Precovenda').AsFloat);
          percent := (Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Desconto').AsFloat);
          try
            tot := tot+(tot * percent)/ 100;
          finally
            Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Total').AsFloat := unid*tot;
            Torcamen_SUB.Post;
            Orcamentos.TotalExecute(self);
          end;
        except
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to implement calculations is actually to move the calculation to your TTable component that the grid is linked to. The Total field shouldn't actually be a field in the database since but rather a calculated field based on values from other fields. Simply add an extra field using the field editor of the table, type in the field name Total, select the correct datatype and then select the field type as Calculated. Click Ok and then add code similar to this for the OnCalcField event of the table:

Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Total').AsFloat := Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('QT').AsFloat * (
Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Precovenda').AsFloat + (Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Precovenda').AsFloat * Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Desconto').AsFloat)/100) ;

A general rule of thumb is that calculated values shouldn't be saved to the database unless really really necessary. It's best to simply add them as calculated fields to the dataset and then link the grid to the dataset. All calculated fields will then be displayed in the grid and each row will show the correct calculated value based on the values for that row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing a business logic (like calculating a total) with User Interaction logic (like the event on which some grid column loses the focus) and that's the source of the erratic behavior of your application.

Looks like not even you know where it happens and where it doesn't happen.

Consider using the Field's events (for example, OnChange event) to perform that kind of calculations.

Lucky you if you're using a dataset with aggregation capabilities (like TClientDataSet), because you can just [declare what you want in a TAggregateField](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29272) and forget about doing calculations "by hand".

**Not your question** but... be careful with the way you're using try/finally also... for example, in this bit of code:

```
try
  tot := tot+(tot * percent)/ 100;
finally
  Torcamen_SUB.FieldByName('Total').AsFloat := unid*tot;
  //other things
end;
```

be aware that if for some reason an exception occurs on the line between the try and finally clauses, the variable tot will have an undefined value (in this case, the result of the previous assignment), so the Assignment to the Torcamen_SUB.total field will be wrong, after all.  I'm not sure if it is really what you want.

Comment: Thak´s you are right about you are sayng. i will rebild the process thank´s.

Comment: I´m using Mdb. Database and when i whant to make a TAggregateField  it doesente let me do it like in the link. is there a way to that?

Comment: @ml are you using ClientDataSets?